# Passing a model in View (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uikit

I'm creating a basic iOS app where I get an array of data(JSON) from an API that contains images. I'm using a `UIViewController` and have a custom `UITableViewCell`.

In order to stop sending network requests, I have created a cache that stores `<url: UIImage>`. The problem is in order to add images to the cache I pass in a model(networking) class to the custom `UITableViewCell`(the view).

My understanding is that the View should have no idea of the model. Is this an acceptable design for MVC or is there a way around this?

Abstract code is below(using the dictionary as a cache right now. Will change to `NSCache` later)
I also am using a protocol/delegate to pass the date between the network and view controller.

```
protocol ModelDelegate {
    
    func dataFetched(_ data:[DataItem])
}

//This is the model(networking) class
class Model {
    
    var delegate: ModelDelegate?
    
    var imagecache: [String: UIImage] = [:]
    
    func getData() {
        let url = URL(string: Constants.DATA_URL)
        
        guard url != nil else {
            print("Invalid URL!")
            return
        }
        
        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            
            if error != nil && data == nil {
                print("There was a data retriving error!")
                return
            }
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let response = try decoder.decode(Data.self, from: data!)
                
                if response.data != nil {
                    
                    let sorteddata = response.data!.sorted(by: { $0.data < $1.data })
                    
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.delegate?.dataFetched(sorteddata)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            } catch  {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        session.resume()
    }
}

//Custom UITableView Cell
class DataViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var dataImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataName: UILabel!
    
    var model = Model()
    var data: DataItem?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
     
    func setCell(_ data: DataItem) {
        self.data = data
        
        self.dataName.text = data.strdata
        
        guard self.data?.thumbnail != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        if let imageData = model.imagecache[self.data!.thumbnail] {
            print("using cache")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.DataImage.image = imageData
            }  
        }
        
        let url = URL(string: self.data!.thumbnail)
        
        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                
                
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.model.imagecache[self.data!.thumbnail] = image
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.DataImage.image = image
                }
        
            }
        }
        
        session.resume()
    }
}

//View Controller

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ModelDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var model = Model()
    var data = [DataItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        model.delegate = self
        
        model.getdata()
    }
    
    func dataFetched(_ data: [DataItem]) {
        self.data = data
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    //TableView methods
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.ID, for: indexPath) as! DataViewCell
        let data = self.categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCell(data)
        
        return cell  
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code is breaking the Solid principle. 
S -> Single responsibility It's good to create a separate HttpUtility for URL calls.
It's good to use "model" in the cellForRowAt index path instead  DataViewCell.

Comment: Views, including UITableViewCell, should have no knowledge of networking logic or any underlying model types. If you're going to stick to MVC, only your view controller should make network calls. It is responsible for interacting between model, network, and views. Also, I would suggest renaming your Model. A model only holds data. A better name is DataProvider or DataService.

Answer (score 1):

A cell is a view, and view should never interact with network layers or underlying data models. It's hard to tell what you are doing because your code doesn't compile so I cooked up an example:

First you have a class named `Model` which isn't really a model. It is a service or data provider. You model is `DataItem`.

Here's what my models usually look like:

```
struct DemoModel: Codable {
    let name: String
    let thumbnailURL: URL?
}
```

I typically have a service layer that looks like this:

```
protocol DataProvider {
    func publisher(forURL url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error>
}

struct DefaultDataProvider: DataProvider {
    func publisher(forURL url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map(\.data)
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct MockDataProvider: DataProvider {
    let data: Data
    func publisher(forURL url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        return Result.Publisher(.success(data))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

The `MockDataProvider` allows me to inject dummy data for testing without making network calls.

Then I would have a service layer that offers services to my viewControllers. In this case, I can fetch any type of object that conforms to `Decodable`, and I can also fetch images with a caching mechanism.

```
struct DecodingService<Output: Decodable> {
    let dataProvider: DataProvider
    func publisher(forURL url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Error> {
        dataProvider
            .publisher(forURL: url)
            .decode(type: Output.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct CachedImageService {
    let dataProvider: DataProvider
    let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    func publisher(forURL url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage, Error> {
        let key = url.absoluteString as NSString

        if let image = cache.object(forKey: key) {
            print("cached")
            return Result.Publisher(.success(image))
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

        print("from web")
        return dataProvider
            .publisher(forURL: url)
            .compactMap(UIImage.init(data:))
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { image in
                self.cache.setObject(image, forKey: key)
            })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Cells should be kept small, and they should be configured or populated by your view controller:

```
class DemoCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let id = "\(DemoCell.self)"

    @IBOutlet weak var thumbImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

In MVC, a view controller should always be the one to make network calls.

```
var thumbService: CachedImageService?
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
var models: [DemoModel] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: DemoCell.id, for: indexPath) as! DemoCell
    let model = models[indexPath.row]

    cell.thumbImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    cell.nameLabel.text = model.name

    guard let url = model.thumbnailURL else { return cell }
    thumbService?
        .publisher(forURL: url)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
        }, receiveValue: { thumb in
            guard indexPath == tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
            cell.thumbImageView.image = thumb
        })
        .store(in: &subscriptions)

    return cell
}
```

As you can see here the view controller makes a network call and then configures the cells.

I would recommend using `Combine` for your network layer as it's much cleaner than using URLSession on it's own with callbacks and such.

Comment: Hi Rob! Thank you for a detailed answer. Honestly, I don't understand all of your code right now but I am slowly digesting it. I have not used Combine but will try to learn it later!